# d3 Zoomable Sunburst with tooltip adjusting the % as it transitions?

Tags: d3.js

I created a zoomable sunburst chart based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307). Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaz_a/nw4pcn2k/2/) so far. What I'm trying to do now is to update the tooltip % value to reflect the new value when the chart is clicked - for example, when the "Traffic" is clicked, after the transition, the new Traffic ring should show a tooltip that says "100%", and the children of the "Traffic" will adjust their % values accordingly. And when "Trucks" is clicked, it should adjust to say "100%"... etc. Please help!!

```
var path = g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .on("click", click)
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    var totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
    var percentage = Math.round((100 * d.value / totalSize) * 10) / 10;
    var percentageString = percentage + "%";
    tooltip.text(d.name + " " + percentageString)
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 0 + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 0 + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });

function click(d) {
  text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
  path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
    .each("end", function(e, i) {
      if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
        var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
        arcText.transition().duration(750)
          .attr("opacity", 1)
          .attr("transform", function() {
            return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
          });
       }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution consists in creating a variable:

```
var percentBase = 100;
```

And, inside function `click`, changing that variable according to the property `percent` of the clicked path:

```
percentBase = parseFloat(d.percent.split("%")[0]);
```

As the central path ("Sources") doesn't have this property, this is also necessary:

```
if(d.name == "Sources") percentBase = 100;
```

Then, inside the `mouseover`, we use this `percentBase` to calculate the percentage.

This is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8sh069ns/

There are some necessary adjustments in the math, but this is up to you now.

Comment: Actually, do you have any idea why "Electric Generation", "Road Dust" and "Other" don't say "100%"? (it's saying "101%", "99%", "101%", respectively)

Comment: Because of the rounding. As I told you, that was just the general idea, now you'll have to fine-tune the math.